# Locale is always French on mozilla Rhino (at least on French platforms)

Tags: java, rhino

I have a PC for which default Locale is "fr", and even if I set 
`context.setLocale(<some locale")` to any other locale, I still have messages in French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work if I do this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("");
context.setLocale(locale);
```

The reason is that there is only the following resource files on Rhino 1.712:
- `org.mozilla.javascript.resources.Messages`
- `org.mozilla.javascript.resources.Messages_fr`
And the code in Rhino does:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.mozilla.javascript.resources.Messages", locale);
```

Which means that Rhino can only find the "fr" resource.